# Keylistener won’t work in Jframe after Jar export

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, actionlistener, keylistener

I have two different scripts, both of them are written in Java. The first script has a keylistener which is called by the main function. Within that main function I also call a specific Jframe, which has a Jlabel which is getting a variable which contains whatever the keylistener returns. The whole thing works, only issue is that whenever I build and run within Netbeans there is no issues and it works perfectly. But as soon as I build the complete Jar and run it by itself as a regular app on a computer the Jframe works, but it won’t get the variable it seems, as it isn’t displaying it. What is weird to me, is the fact that it works when it is run in Netbeans, but as soon as it is outside where it is gonna be used, it doesn’t work.

My two script can be seen below.

### Script 1 with listener

This is the one which has the keylistener and creates a variable(string) containing the keylistener value.

```
public class Stang2 implements NativeKeyListener {

    public static String getSfF = "";
    static File bilDi = new File("file.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        if(!bilDi.exists()){
           //do something later
        } else {
            tastCall();
        }

    }

    static void tastCall(){
        botShik();      
    }

    static void botShik(){
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new Stang2());
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                getSfF = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
                System.out.println(stringCarry);
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    public static String pubSen() {
        return getSfF;
    }

}
```

### Script 2 which is the actual Jframe

this is the one which gets the variable(string) with the key logged from the listener. It is then set to display it as a Jlabel which is updated every 500 milliseconds by a timer.

```
public class TingS extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String senTen = Stang2.pubSen();
            jLabel2.setText(senTen);
            System.out.println(senTen);
        }
    });

    public TingS() {
        initComponents();
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: log file output

Comment: @KOUROUMA I appreciate the feedback, I am sorry but I am not completely sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [mcve].